# LDIF Disable script

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a long list of users to disable every week and I am trying to figure out how can I write an LDIF script to check if users in AD are disabled and if not to disable them and move them to another OU.

Environment: Windows Server 2008 R2

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with PowerShell.

The general process would be something like this:

- Read the file line by line with the usernames you want to disable, and loop over the usernames
- Use [`Get-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx)`$username` to get the AD object for the users one by one
- Check the objects you get, if they are disabled. You can use the `Enabled` property on the ADUser for this.
- If they need disabling, use the [`Disable-ADAccount`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617197.aspx) and  [`Move-ADObject`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617248.aspx) cmdlets to accomplish that.

You may even be able to do this as a oneliner if you really wanted to. Something like:

```
Get-Content userstodisable.txt | Get-ADUser | Where Enabled -eq True | Disable-ADAccount -PassThru | Move-ADObject -TargetPath OU=Disabled,DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com
```

Feel free to hack around with this until you get it right.